# Galaxy S4 stock browser css positioning

Tags: android, html, css

I am testing a page with a sticky footer. On the GS4 stock browser ONLY (not visible on android chrom), I get the sticky footer floating up and down the page as I scroll up and down. The footer also seems to have a stutter-looking effect. I've tested the same page on iphone 5 and gs3. This is my CSS flow:

```
.bar {
   background-color: #F7F7F7;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
   font-size: 13px;
}
.bar .footer-icon-holder {
    padding: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 5em;
 }
.bar .footer-holder {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 54px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    bottom:0;
   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
   position: fixed;
}
```

and the footer html:

```
<div class="footer"  ng-controller='footerController'>
<div id = "footer" class="bar">
    <div style="margin:0 auto;">
        <div class="footer-holder">
            <div class="footer-icon-holder" ng-click="clickPic('home')" >
                <div ng-show="homeSelected">
                    <img ng-src={{imageOnHome}} class="footerimg">
                    <div class="toolbar-img-text">home</div>
                </div>
                <div  ng-hide="homeSelected">
                    <img ng-src={{imageOffHome}} class="footerimg">
                    <div class="toolbar-img-text">home</div>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "floating up and down"? So it's not fixed at all, or it's partially fixed? Either way, it sounds like a browser bug and not a CSS problem.

Comment: its very abnormal behavior so thats the best way to describe it. I am confident that it is a browser bug but unfortunately, i am trying to find a workaround to this.

Comment: Start by [determining whether the browser truly supports `position:fixed` at all](http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/). That page also lists some JS-based solutions.